# Composer: Develop directly in vendor packages

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have a PHP project where I use composer.

My own main library is actually a required package, as I'm also building a "standalone version" for people to install (not just the library), thus it lands in the `vendor` directory.

Most of the time I spend developing the project happens in that vendor package, which is a Git clone already, however not on any branch. I can change that quickly enough by running `git checkout master`. However, every time I run `composer update`, it either complains about the directory being dirty, or checks out a new copy, where I have to start without being on a branch once more.

So, my question: is there some mode for Composer to e.g. only fetch the changes in that repo? Or what would be the preferred way to develop (or just contribute to) a vendor package at the same time as developing the main package?

Comment: `git stash` before you run composer and load the stash afterward?

Comment: That's just a workaround, though, and exactly the kind of thing I want to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of a couple minutes ago composer updates will now ask you whether you want to revert the changes or do a stash/apply before/after the package update. This should help quite a bit with such problems, see https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1188 for details.

Comment: I've tried with the latest version of composer `825b4b9c63a29c586d005de8dbbcfdfeb86bbf6f` and with `1.0.0-alpha9`. I still don't see the `s` option. I only have `y, n, v, ?` for options when my composer encounters a dirty package. Any ideas?

Comment: @awei stash is only available for git packages, maybe your package is svn or hg?

Comment: @Seldaek: it's definitely a git package. i wrote the module myself. Can you confirm the `s` option exists in `composer@1.0-dev`?

Answer (score 2):

You can update only a single or few packages by specifying them at the end for the update comamnd:

```
composer update pkg1 pkg2 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

After all these years... I have created a [package](https://github.com/franzliedke/studio) that makes it easy to develop Composer packages while using them, making use of Composer's "path repositories", but without having to touch composer.json, which might not be desirable in a repository shared with other developers.

Shameless plug, but this was my own question, so I hope this is okay. :)