# composer update ignore deps

Tags: composer-php

How can i tell composer to ignore certain deps while running update?

I know i can update certain packages with:

```
php composer.phar update vendor/package vendor/package2
```

But i would like to have it the other way around by telling composer to update all except these packages.

In my case the command would be much shorter than the above, since i just want to ignore some experimental bundle.
And i dont want to delete it fully, which would probably happen, if I clear the bundle from the require list.

Comment: Have you tried locking the version you want to use by making the version number more explicit?

Comment: its rather about keeping local changes (i know you shouldnt have local changes in vendor, but it just happened)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not update a specific package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314091/do-not-update-a-specific-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible by now.

However you can try to shorten the explicit update calls with wildcards:

```
php composer.phar update doctrine/*
```

As described here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update

But composer will ask you if you want to keep local changes if composer detects such.

> ```
> The package has modified files:
> D code/controller/yourFile.php
> Discard changes [y,n,v,s,?]?
> ```

Also you can use the stash/apply mechanism for git repos which is featured in composer.
https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1188

Also helpful:
[Composer: Develop directly in vendor packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624653/composer-develop-directly-in-vendor-packages)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it wasn't possible at that time, but nowadays you can do it like this

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs vendor/package
```

Comment: ignore-platform-reqs is about platform requirements like the installed php version. this will not help in ignoring certain packages while updating