# Do not update a specific package

Tags: composer-php

Is there a way to tell composer that each time I do a `composer update` I want him to ignore a specific package?

Comment: IIRC a flag to do things like this is coming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I don't know if there is any way to tell `composer` to exclude one specific package from updating but you can tell which packages to update as

```
composer update <package> <package2>; // or
php composer.phar update <package> <package2>;
```

For example,

```
composer update foo/package1 bar/package2; // or
php composer.phar update foo/package1 bar/package2;
```

Also, I think, if  you don't list them in `composer.json` (remove after installation) by yourself, then they will not be updated unless also specified in the list.

**From Composer:**
If you only want to install or update one dependency, you can whitelist them:

```
$ php composer.phar update monolog/monolog [...]
```

[Check this link](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/450) and also check [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file).

**Update :** (found on internet but not tested)

To do that, just remove the package from `composer.lock`

Comment: I tried removing the package from composer.lock but doesn't work. When running the update, composer puts it back. Updating all the other packages manually it's not what I need (but if I don't get a better answer / solution, I'll mark your answer as the solution. Thank you @sheikh-heera

Comment: hey! welcome man, did you check the composer's site, it has been said to mention packages, something like `php composer.phar update monolog/monolog [...]` and also, did you try to remove the package from `composer.json` too ?

Comment: if you remove a package from composer.json, it will be removed when you make a `composer update`

Answer (score 41):

Have you considered specifying the required version for the package you are trying to ignore?  For instance:

```
"require": {
    "some/package": "~1.2"
}
```

This may get updated, because you are saying any version >=1.2,<2.0,  But if you strictly say you want only version 1.0, you should not see any updates to that package:

```
"require": {
    "some/package": "1.2"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Definitely it should be accepted answer - no playing with composer.lock file

Comment: I have a version called `dev-master 1910041`

Answer (score 4):

To ignore a specific package, you can use [`provide`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#provide) (if it's part of your own package) or [`replace`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace). This tells Composer that you wish to provide/replace a specific package, so it won't download it.

Here is the `composer.json` file example which should work:

```
{
    "require": {
        "radic/tmp-underscore-php": "~1.2.0"
    },
    "replace": {
        "patchwork/utf8": "*"
    }
}
```

In this example, the `patchwork/utf8` package would be ignored on `composer install` or `update`.

To exclude specific version, see: [Composer exclude specific versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21860659/55075).

Answer (score 3):

**Update: Only availble for composer versions 1.0.0-alpha6 and lower. Using it in version 1.0.0-alpha7 and higher will remove all packages in "require-dev".**

I believe currently you can trick composer with some mess if you can afford it in your project. Something like: Put all packages you don't want to update in `"require-dev"` and run updates with `composer update --no-dev`

Just be careful of that if you run `composer install` as i recall they will be removed from your project.

All this trickery is really nasty, so we should wait for official way of doing things like that, personally i update packages explicitly specifying them

Comment: This finally did the trick for me. Definitely the only solution to leave specific packages untouched. tried every other possibility before.

Comment: The `composer update --no-dev` removes all "require-dev" packages, do not use it. I learned it in the hard way...

Comment: @Clyff thats correct just checked, it works for versions < 1.0.0-alpha7. It was rewritten after/including in 1.0.0-alpha7.

Comment: @arma Thank you for updating the answer :)