# Using SVN and composer together - Version control of the vendor directory

Tags: php, svn, composer-php

This is how I use composer and svn together:

In my development version, I run composer to download required packages to the `vendor` directory. I then commit the `vendor` directory to svn together with the rest of the development folder. The production build makes a copy of the `vendor` folder.

I know, it is recommended not to commit the `vendor` directory in svn (see [SVN Repo in vendor with Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613773/svn-repo-in-vendor-with-composer)), but I want to be safe for the case when a `composer update` may break my application. It allows me to rollback everything in that case to the last stable state.

The problem with how composer works is that the checked out svn repo breaks, if composer deletes whole directories.

I would switch to the recommended practice and only check in `composer.lock` and `composer.json` into svn, if I knew how to rollback an eventual breaking `composer update`. Can somebody explain this to me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `composer.lock` and run `composer install` (not update) you are sure that you'll get dependencies which are "locked" by you.

Running `composer update` ignores entries in `composer.lock` and tries to download latest dependencies allowed by `composer.json`.

Comment: This means that if a `composer update` breaks something, I just can delete the `vendor` folder, revert `composer.lock` and run `composer install` ? What are the guarantees that I can always rely on packagist like that ?

Comment: You should never run `composer update` on production, only `composer install`. You can run update locally an after verifying that nothing broke, just commit `composer.lock`.

Comment: Yes, I run `composer update` only in the development environment.

Comment: I just tried it out now. I just recreated my vendor directory just out of composer.lock.